# image upload-showing image on a form

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am using netbeans6.7.1 and phpmyadmin for my db to develop a java application 
to manage students records
i want to upload students photos through browsing by clicking a browse buton which i have 
included in my interface

*I mean when i click on that button a JFilechooser pops up which filter only images(i have acomplished this)*

1. what i need is when i click on the "Attach button" of the JFilechooser, i want the image i chose to be attached to a jtextArea on the form i'm working with and the JFilechooser be diposed off.
2. Also how i can save this form together with the image to a database table

Is there a place where i can find a good guide/tutorial about that

Answer (score 3):

```
JFileChooser                chooser;
FileNameExtensionFilter     filter;
chooser =   new JFileChooser();
filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("jpeg, gif and png files", "jpg", "gif", "png");
chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
jButton1.addActionListener(this);
if(e.getSource()==jButton1)
    {
        int i = chooser.showOpenDialog(jPanel1);
        if(i==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {
            jPanel2.removeAll();
            jPanel2.repaint();
            File image   =   chooser.getSelectedFile();
            ImageIcon photo   =   new ImageIcon(image.getAbsolutePath());               
            //jPanel2.add(new JLabel(photo));
            JLabel label=new JLabel("",photo,JLabel.CENTER);
            jPanel2.add(label,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            jPanel2.repaint();// sets a default image in image field.
            jPanel2.revalidate();
        }
    }
```

Note:You should set  borderlayout for jpanel2
and the selected image size must be the size of jpanel2